# Get raw Python objects from KernelManager

Tags: python, jupyter-kernel

When running code in a Jupyter kernel it is possible to get the `iopub` or the `shell` messages from the respective channels. Is is possible to extract the raw python objects from the kernel as well?

Say for the below code

```
code = """a = {'a': 1}
b = {'b': 2}
"""


class Shell:
    def __init__(self):
        km = KernelManager()
        km.start_kernel()

        client = km.client()
        client.start_channels()

        client.execute(code)

        print(client.get_iopub_msg())
        print(client.get_shell_msg())
```

I want to retrieve the actual objects `a` and `b` so that they can be used in the current python application. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround for it by using `dill` to dump the entire session inside the kernel

```
dill.dump_session()
```

And then load it in the main application

```
dill.load_session()
```